# GA BigQuery: Calculating pageviews with a custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Using GA BigQuery data, I am trying to calculate the total pageviews across 3 dimensions: date, device category, and a custom dimension (called "type" here).

So the desired output is:
[image]

So the total pageviews should be listed for each date, device, and type combination.

I used the following query to get this result. I need to unnest the "type" dimension because it is a custom dimension.

```
#standardsql

SELECT date, device, cd6_type, SUM(pvs) AS pageviews    

FROM(
  SELECT 
        date,
        fullvisitorID, 
        visitID, 
        totals.pageviews AS pvs,
        device.deviceCategory AS device
       , MAX(IF(hcd.index = 6, hcd.value, NULL)) AS cd6_type

        FROM `ga360-173318.62903073.ga_sessions_*` AS t,
              UNNEST (t.hits) AS h,
              UNNEST (h.customDimensions) AS hcd

        WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN (SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2019-07-08'))
                                AND (SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2019-07-08'))

        AND h.type = "PAGE"

        GROUP BY
              date,
              fullVisitorID,
              visitID,
              totals.pageviews,
              device
   )

GROUP BY date, device, cd6_type
```

The problem is that my results do not match what appears in GA; the query returns fewer results. In GA, the above results are:

- 180,812 mobile, Type A pageviews (compared to 149,149 in GBQ)
- 30,949 tablet, Type A pageviews (compared to 16,863 in GBQ)

I'm not sure why they don't match across the 2 systems, and am wondering how others calculate total pageviews across dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

You're cross joining with `customdimensions`, so you're not counting pages, but custom dimensions on pages. Just don't do this cross join, you don't need it if you get your custom dimension using a subquery.

```sql
#standardsql

SELECT  
  date,
  device.deviceCategory AS device
  ,(SELECT hcd.value FROM h.customdimensions AS hcd WHERE hcd.index = 6 ) AS cd6_type
  ,COUNT(1) as pageviews
FROM  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`  AS t,
      UNNEST(t.hits) AS h

WHERE _table_suffix between '20170801' and '20170801' 

AND h.type = "PAGE"

GROUP BY date, device, cd6_type
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! If I attempt this query, I get the following error:

"Correlated aliases referenced in the from clause must refer to arrays that are valid to access from the outer query, but h refers to an array that is not valid to access after GROUP BY or DISTINCT in the outer query at [12:32]." Line 12 is where the suggested customdimensions subquery is located.

Comment: True - I missed the `group by` ... that's also how you counted pages, I guess. But the cross join eliminated all pages without any customdimensions. corrected my post

Comment: I just realized you counted totals.pageviews after cross join with hits. That's not ideal, since totals contains session information that gets repeated with every hit if you cross join with hits. Corrected and shortened the query again :D

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann thank you so much for that, the totals.pageviews at session level vs. dimensions at hit level broke my brain before I had read this :-D